# Responsive css grid with responsive width for items between 220px and 250px

Tags: css, responsive, css-grid, minmax

I want my grid items to be minimum of 220px and a maximum of 250px and to be responsive. So first I tried this grid:

```
1) grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 250px));
```

Its good, but the problem is that it either makes an item of 220px or 250px. In does not make an item anything in between (e.g 201px, 202px, 203px etc.) depending on the container size. Anyway that is how minmax is suppose to work, but it did not accomplish what I wanted.

So I tried this code:

```
2) grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 1fr));
```

It was almost perfect, but the item would eventually go above 250px and end up at 263px, 277px and etc, again depending on the container size. So to fix this, I naturally added to every item:

```
3) max-width:250px;
```

It solved what I wanted, but created a new problem. The grid-gap which was set to 15px, started growing between the items going beyond 15px. So can I achieve what I want?

I want grid items to be between 220px and 250px and change between those size depending on the grid's container and I want the grid gap to be exactly at 15px.

Here is how the end result looks: https://jsfiddle.net/01w293sv/2/

Comment: Frankly what you are describing **is not a grid** to my mind. You just want a series of auto-width elements in a wrapping environment with min and max widths. That doesn't sound like a *grid" to me, it's sounds like a series of inline-block elements.

Comment: any tips on how to make this?

Comment: Sure. Stop thinking of this as a grid. Use flexbox and have min and max widths on your elements.

Comment: I dunno I can't figure it out :((( Whenever I try the "gap" between items will eventually change. I want it to remain same and be items to change between 220 - 250px :/